# maven downloading jars freezing

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.1
From this IDE I run first build and wait forever for artifacts downloading...

f.e.

```
cd D:\work\project1; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02" D:\\work\\project1\\tools\\apache-maven-3.0.2\\bin\\mvn.bat -DskipTests=true -Dverbose install
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building project1 1.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-benchmark/3.3.0/lucene-benchmark-3.3.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers/3.3.0/lucene-analyzers-3.3.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/solr/solr-core/3.3.0/solr-core-3.3.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/solr/solr-solrj/3.3.0/solr-solrj-3.3.0.jar
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/3.3.0/lucene-core-3.3.0.jar
```

I've tried to add a mirror to my maven configuration:

```
<mirror>
    <id>uk.maven.org</id>
    <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

the same problem but it is freezing on another jar downloading.

I'll be thankful for any advice.

Thank you.

P.S. I've changed Build->Compile -> Java Platform settings: from JDK1.7 to JDK1.6 - and it is working well...

P.P.S. Thank you guys. Every answer was helpful.

Comment: To determine if it's a problem with IDE, open command line, navigate to your project and launch `mvn clean package` and see if it takes less time.

Comment: You should update to at least Maven 3.0.3 and recheck the problem on command line..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you use an anti virus solutions with a webproxy like Avira Antivir? If so, try to disable it.

Don't forget to empty your repository folder or remove the artifact folder which are created for the missing artifacts.

Comment: I'm not using Avira, but temporary disable my AV - solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Post Your `pom.xml` please. Maybe there are some artifacts that are not available anymore on the repositories that You configured. Do You get any timeouts?

Try to use Your browser to navigate through the repositories structure of the repository that contains the artifact that is not downloading.